# Is there a quick way to remove flaps in my mesh?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

Here is what I'm dealing with, there's a flap in my mesh, its hard to isolate the individual vertices of the flap in order to dissolve them:

[image: flap example]

Is there like a brush which merges nearby surfaces into one surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait nvm, just found out that turning on `Dynamic Topology` with the `collapse` refine method on a draw brush somehow does exactly that.